# XSLT 1.0 summarize of multiple nodes with different data

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT 1.0, I want to create new tags for all unique values inside the `PackageTypeCode` tags. The value for the new tags should be the sum of its' respective occurrences.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TransportJob xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="11.1">
    <Consignment>
        <GoodsItem>
            <PackageTypeCode>PE</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
        <GoodsItem>
            <PackageTypeCode>PC</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
        <GoodsItem>
            <PackageTypeCode>PE</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
        <GoodsItem>
            <PackageTypeCode>PC</PackageTypeCode>
        </GoodsItem>
    </Consignment>
</TransportJob>
```

In the example I have two `PackageTypeCode`'s that are `PC` and two `PackageTypeCode`'s that are `PE`. These should return the following:

```xml
<extraGoodsData>
    <product type="PC">
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </product>
    <product type="PE">
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </product>
</extraGoodsData>
```

The best way seems to be creating multiple variables with an incrementing variable. However, since there can be infinite occurrences of these, I don't want to write >10 variables and manually check for each unique value.

In XSTL 2.0 this would be trivial with e.g. [fn:matches](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_matches.html).

EDIT:

```
<test>
<xsl:for-each select="GoodsItem[count(. | key('product_by_key', PackageTypeCode)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('product_by_key', PackageTypeCode)">
                    <xsl:sort select="PackageTypeCode" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="PackageTypeCode" />
                </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
        </test>
```

this is my current code which generates this

```
<test>
        <types>PC</types>
        <types>PC</types>
        <types>PC</types>
        <types>PC</types>
        <types>PE</types>
    </test>
```

which is sort of on the right track but now i need to somehow count these. i Dont think this is the correct way to do it but i feel im kind of on the right track(note i used a different source file with more types so thats why there's 5"types")

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. The preferred grouping method in XSLT 1.0 is the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Going by your example you linked im not really sure how im supposed to use the grouping to then count the different PackageTypeCodes. i tried below example but it gave an error when transforming using notepad++ plugin
```xml
<xsl:for-each select="//GoodsItem[count(. | key('product_by_key', PackageTypeCode)[1]) = 1]">
  <xsl:sort select="PackageTypeCode" />
  <xsl:value-of select="PackageTypeCode" />,<br />
  <xsl:for-each select="key('product_by_key', PackageTypeCode)">
   <xsl:sort select="PackageTypeCode" />
   <xsl:value-of select="PackageTypeCode" />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and show your attempt there. If you get en error, show the exact error message.

Comment: sorry about that haven't used SO before so I didn't know the comments worked that way, I have Edited my main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-pkg" match="GoodsItem" use="PackageTypeCode" />

<xsl:template match="/TransportJob">
    <extraGoodsData>
        <!-- create a group for each distinct PackageTypeCode -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Consignment/GoodsItem[count(. | key('item-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode)[1]) = 1]">
            <product type="{PackageTypeCode}">
                <quantity>
                    <!-- count current group -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('item-by-pkg', PackageTypeCode))" />
                </quantity>
            </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </extraGoodsData>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are a savior. It works perfectly.
Im just a bit curious the first part with the Goodsitem[count(. part, how does it work? it takes the node GoodsItem gives it a value of 1 for each found and creates 1 key for each of the same value found? and then we can use that to count the unique keys?

Comment: It tests each `Goodsitem` node against the first node of the group with the same `PackageTypeCode`. If it is the same node (i.e. if the union of the two nodes being compared contains 1 node), then the node is processed. This results in one `product` node being created for each group.